# trouble connecting to oauth2/api with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, mapmyfitness

I'm trying to connect to the mapmyfitness api via oauth2. However I am getting an error whenever i try to connect.

this is the config file..

```js
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :mapmyfitness, ENV['wn3ghaaqgbpnztsupsyfvswd3gtprvm9'], ENV['fRMsDbrNQJBgFUBkYReuqKffFKWTzZWVUKz9jCSTeVJ']
end
```

Using that should allow me to at least log in to mapmyfitness, however whenever i try to connect (it redirects to https://www.mapmyfitness.com/v7.1/oauth2/authorize/confirm)... i get this error in the browser "An unauthorized client tried to access your resources."

I'm not sure how to fix this, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unless wn3ghaaqgbpnztsupsyfvswd3gtprvm9 is a key that you set in your environment to equal your mapmyfitness access secret / token - then you need to remove the ENV parts - it probably should look more like:   `provider :mapmyfitness, wn3ghaaqgbpnztsupsyfvswd3gtprvm9', 'fRMsDbrNQJBgFUBkYReuqKffFKWTzZWVUKz9jCSTeVJ'`

Comment: yeah those are both key/secrets... if i take away the ENV i get hit with this error when trying to access mapmyfitness "The requested redirect didn't match the client settings."

Comment: That's good.  Because you're no longer unauthorized - now it's just telling you that your callback url is wrong :)

Comment: ok, good. I have my callback address set as "http://localhost.mapmyapi.com:3000/callback" as per their docs here...https://developer.underarmour.com/docs/v71_OAuth_2_Demo (unfortunately their are for python) because i'm just developing on my local machine (host is localhost:3000).. any tips on how to change it to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The two issues you have

1. Only use ENV[] if your data is stored in the shell evironment - the "safer" way to to do this is to store the info in secret.yml
2. Your callback URL needs to match what Omniauth is expecting -- it should be http://localhost.mapmyapi.com:12345/auth/mapmyfitness/callback as described here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application

Example for your omniauth initializer using secrets

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :mapmyfitness, Rails.application.secrets.mapmyfitness_provider_key, Rails.application.secrets.mapmyfitness_provider_secret
end
```

Then your secrets.yml would look like:

```
development:
  mapmyfitness_provider_key: wn3ghaaqgbpnztsupsyfvswd3gtprvm9
  mapmyfitness_provider_secret: fRMsDbrNQJBgFUBkYReuqKffFKWTzZWVUKz9jCSTeVJ
```

Obviously you'll have a different line for production.  Remember also that now that your keys are out there for the world you might consider requesting a new set of credentials :)

Also usually important to remember not to your check your config/secrets.yml file into version control - instead copy it with deployment.

Might try using lvh.me instead of mapmyfitness's localhost passthrough.

Change your callback URL registered at mapmyfitness to

```
http://lvh.me:3000/auth/mapmyfitness/callback
```

Then in your browser - visit http://lvh.me:3000

Obviously you'll need to make sure that whatever port your using the same port your rails server is running on.

Comment: i set the callback address as that, and then added the appropriate routes but i'm still getting the "The requested redirect..." error, i'm not sure where i'm going wrong here

Comment: First of all, you'd need to check that your server is running on port 12345 - but I it is possible something isn't quite right with their proxy (passing localhost.mapmyapi.com back to your local machine. -- So instead - I would try using a public localhost passthrough, like lvh.me or localtest.me , i'll edit.